# Updating ResultSets with SQL Array types in JDBC / PostgreSQL

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to use a SQL Array type with PostgreSQL 8.4 and the JDBC4 driver.

My column is defined as follows:

```
nicknames           CHARACTER VARYING(255)[]    NOT NULL
```

and I'm trying to update it thusly:

```
row.updateArray("nicknames", 
    connection.createArrayOf("CHARACTER VARYING", p.getNicknames().toArray()));
```

(`p.getNicknames()` returns a `List<String>`)

but I'm seeing:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
>   Unable to find server array type for
>   provided name CHARACTER VARYING.  at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.createArrayOf(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:67)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.createArrayOf(Jdbc4Connection.java:21)

Unfortunately, the Array types don't seem to be well documented - I've not found mention of exactly how to do this for PostgreSQL anywhere :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change "CHARACTER VARYING" to "varchar".  The command-line `psql` client accepts the type name "CHARACTER VARYING", but the JDBC driver does not.

The source for `org.postgresql.jdbc2.TypeInfoCache` contains a list of accepted type names.

Consider part of the ambiguously-worded contract for [`createArrayOf()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

> The typeName is a database-specific name which may be the name of a built-in type, a user-defined type or a standard SQL type supported by this database.

I always assumed driver implementors interpret the phrases "database-specific name" and "supported by this database" to mean "accept whatever you want".  But maybe you could file this as a bug against the Postgres JDBC driver.

Good luck.

Comment: Ach, you're right.  I assumed "database-specific" meant "whatever the DB uses" which as you point out is wrong.

Also worth noting that it *seems* to be case sensitive, unlike just about everything else.  Thanks!