# Array with UserType in Hibernate and PostgreSQL --> MappingException

Tags: java, arrays, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to write a class implementing UserType to deal with arrays in Hibernate/JPA. 
I used the following posts 
[mapping a postgres array with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate/1647660#1647660) and [Hibernate/JPA/HSQL : How to create a Dialect mapping for User Type ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393334/hibernate-jpa-hsql-how-to-create-a-dialect-mapping-for-user-type-array/5412235#5412235) to build a solution but I cannot get it to work. 
I created a new Spring Roo project just to test it. Here are the different files (all java classes are located in the package test):

- persistence.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <properties>
      <!--  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/> -->
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="test.PostgreSQLDialectArray"/>
      <!-- value="create" to build a new database on each run; value="update" to modify an existing database; value="create-drop" means the same as "create" but also drops tables when Hibernate closes; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
      <!-- Uncomment the following two properties for JBoss only -->
      <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl" value="false" /-->
      <!-- property name="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners" value="false" /-->
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
  ```
- TestArray.java

  ```
  package test;

  import java.math.BigInteger;
  import java.security.SecureRandom;

  import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
  import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
  import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
  import org.springframework.roo.addon.serializable.RooSerializable;
  import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

  @RooJavaBean
  @RooToString
  @RooSerializable
  public class TestArray {


       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();


       public String nextSessionId()
       {
           return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           ApplicationContext context;
   context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml");
           int[] array = new int[1428];
           TestArray test = new TestArray();
           Blabla blabla = new Blabla();
           int nb = 1428;

           for(int i = 0 ; i < nb ; i++)
           array[i] = test.random.nextInt();

            //         blabla.setTest(array);
            //         blabla.persist();
            //        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(blabla.getTest()));

           System.out.println(java.sql.Types.ARRAY);
           System.out.println("Done");
       }
  }
  ```
- Blabla.java

  ```
  package test;

  import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
  import org.springframework.roo.addon.entity.RooEntity;
  import org.springframework.roo.addon.javabean.RooJavaBean;
  import org.springframework.roo.addon.tostring.RooToString;

  @RooJavaBean
  @RooToString
  @RooEntity
  public class Blabla {

      @Type(type = "test.IntArrayUserType")
      private int[] array;
  }
  ```
- PostgreSQLDialectArray

  ```
  package test;

  import java.sql.Types;


  public class PostgreSQLDialectArray extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect{

      public PostgreSQLDialectArray() { 
          super(); 
          registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "array"); 
      }
   }
  ```
- IntArrayUserType.java (basically the same than in [mapping a postgres array with hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate/1647660#1647660))

  ```
  package test;
  import java.io.Serializable;
  import java.sql.Array;
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.SQLException;

  import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
  import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;



  public class IntArrayUserType implements UserType {

      protected static final int  SQLTYPE = java.sql.Types.ARRAY;

      private int[] toPrimitive(Integer[] array){
          int[] a = new int[array.length];
          for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
              a[i] = array[i];
          return a;
      }

      private Integer[] toObject(int[] array){
          Integer[] a = new Integer[array.length];
          for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
              a[i] = array[i];
          return a;
      }

      @Override
      public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
          Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
          Integer[] javaArray = (Integer[]) array.getArray();
          return toPrimitive(javaArray);
      }

      @Override
      public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object object, final int i) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
          System.out.println("test null safe set...");
          Connection connection = statement.getConnection();

          int[] castObject = (int[]) object;
          Integer[] integers = toObject(castObject);
          Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", integers);

          statement.setArray(i, array);
          System.out.println("test null safe set...");
      }

      @Override
      public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
          return cached;
      }

      @Override
      public Object deepCopy(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
          return o == null ? null : ((int[]) o).clone();
      }

      @Override
      public Serializable disassemble(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
          return (Serializable) o;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
          return x == null ? y == null : x.equals(y);
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
          return o == null ? 0 : o.hashCode();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isMutable() {
          return false;
      }

      @Override
      public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
          return original;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<int[]> returnedClass() {
          return int[].class;
      }

      @Override
      public int[] sqlTypes() {
          return new int[] { SQLTYPE };
      }
  }
  ```

And now the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at test.TestArray.main(TestArray.java:29)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 15 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:77)
at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:100)
at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:296)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:208)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.sqlCreateString(Table.java:418)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaCreationScript(Configuration.java:1099)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:106)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:372)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
... 27 more
```

So I guess that the dialect that I created is not used at all or is wrong but I don't know why. I think that the @Type annotation should do the mapping but I have seen some  tags but I do not know if they are needed in this example and if they are, where do I had them? It's been two days that I am stuck with this problem and I am getting desperate. Could you help me debug this program? Please.
Thank you very much in advance.

**Edit 0:**

The persistence.xml file seem to find the correct dialect but the function getTypeName(2003) throws the errors above after doing registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "array"). BTW, I am using Hibernate 3.6.4.Final and postgresql 8.4-702.jdbc3.

**Edit 1:**

I added the following line to PostgreSQLDialectArray constructor:

```
registerColumnType(Types.ARRAY, "integer[$l]" );
```

which seems to partially solve the problem. However, now I get another error:

```
2013-01-09 11:14:30,281 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Unsuccessful: create table blabla (id int8 not null, array int[255], name varchar(255), test int4 not null, version int4, primary key (id))
2013-01-09 11:14:30,282 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « array »
  Position: 40
```

Apparently, hibernate still does not know how to create a table with an array in it...

**Edit 2:**

It seems that postgresql didn't like the fact that my column was called "array". I change that and it worked. The table is created by hibernate with an array of integer.

BUT I cannot save any array in it with hibernate because of a problem in the UserType implementation. Apparently, the creation of the array fails with createArrayOf. I am reading some threads on this matter telling to access the underlying connection instead of the wrapper. I think I am going to open a new thread linking to this one because this problem is quite different.

The stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;
at test.IntArrayUserType.nullSafeSet(IntArrayUserType.java:59)
at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:140)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2184)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2430)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2874)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:76)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$afterReturning$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$3$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:78)
at test.Blabla_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$test_Blabla_Roo_Entity$test_Blabla$persist(Blabla_Roo_Entity.aj:56)
at test.Blabla.persist(Blabla.java:1)
at test.Blabla_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$test_Blabla_Roo_Entity$test_Blabla$persist(Blabla_Roo_Entity.aj)
at test.TestArray.main(TestArray.java:39)
```

**Edit 3:**

Finally, after the following modifications, the UserType for integer arrays works:

- Add this line in applicationContext.xml in:

  `<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">`
             `....` 
             `<property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true" />`
      `</bean>`
- Modify the nullSafeSet from IntArrayUserType

  ```
      @Override
      public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object object, final int i) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
          Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
          int[] castObject = (int[]) object;
          Integer[] integers = toObject(castObject);
          Connection conn = ((DelegatingConnection) connection).getInnermostDelegate();
          Array array = conn.createArrayOf("integer", integers);
          statement.setArray(i, array);
      }
  ```

BUT there is still a problem when getting all the entries from the table blabla:
The function findAllBlablas does not work properly and only returns the first entry...

**Edit 4:**

In fact, it worked great but the eclipse console was not able to print all data. That's all!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mapping a postgres array with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 4):

```
__________ HibernateSessionFactory.xml ___________________________

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!-- <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.test.model.PostgreSQLDialectArray</prop>              
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>                
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property>



    ______________ PostgreSQLDialectArray.java _______________________


package com.test.model;

import java.sql.Types;

public class PostgreSQLDialectArray extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect{

    public PostgreSQLDialectArray() {

        super();    

        System.out.println("Register Hibernate Type ... ");
        registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "array");

        System.out.println("Register Column Type ... ");
        registerColumnType(Types.ARRAY, "integer[]");

    }
}



_____________ CustomArrayType.java ______________________________


package com.test.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.sql.Array;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

 public class CustomArrayType implements UserType
 {

     protected static final int  SQLTYPE = java.sql.Types.ARRAY;

     private int[] toPrimitive(Integer[] array){
         int[] a = new int[array.length];
         for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
             a[i] = array[i];
         return a;
     }

     private Integer[] toObject(int[] array){
         Integer[] a = new Integer[array.length];
         for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
             a[i] = array[i];
         return a;
     }

     @Override
     public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, SessionImplementor session, final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
         Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
         Integer[] javaArray = (Integer[]) array.getArray();
         return toPrimitive(javaArray);
     }

     @Override
     public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object object, final int i, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
         System.out.println("test null safe set...");
         Connection connection = statement.getConnection();

         int[] castObject = (int[]) object;
         Integer[] integers = toObject(castObject);
         Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", integers);

         statement.setArray(i, array);
         System.out.println("test null safe set...");
     }

     @Override
     public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
         return cached;
     }

     @Override
     public Object deepCopy(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
         return o == null ? null : ((int[]) o).clone();
     }

     @Override
     public Serializable disassemble(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
         return (Serializable) o;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
         return x == null ? y == null : x.equals(y);
     }

     @Override
     public int hashCode(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
         return o == null ? 0 : o.hashCode();
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isMutable() {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
         return original;
     }

     @Override
     public Class<int[]> returnedClass() {
         return int[].class;
     }

     @Override
     public int[] sqlTypes() {
         return new int[] { SQLTYPE };
     }

}



____________ MyClass.java ___________________________

package com.test.model;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "MyClass")
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2520209406925143850L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Type(type = "com.test.model.CustomArrayType")
    @Column(name = "arrayDay", nullable = true)
    private int[] arrayDay;           

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public int[] getArrayDay() {
        return arrayDay;
    }

    public void setArrayDay(int[] arrayDay) {
        this.arrayDay = arrayDay;
    }  

}



______________ ArrayTypeTests.java ___________________________



package com.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.test.model.MyClass;
import com.test.service.MyClassService;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context.xml" })
public class ArrayTypeTests implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private MyClassService myClassService;

    public static ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Test
    public void test_() {
       System.out.println("Test junit");
    }

    @Test
    public void test_arrayDays() {

    System.out.println("\n - Start test_array - ");
    MyClass myClass = myClassService.getMyClassById(1L);
    if (myClass != null) {
        int[] array = myClass.getArrayDay();
        System.out.println("\n valor1:" + array[0]);
        System.out.println("\n valor2:" + array[1]);
        System.out.println("\n\n test_array OK ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("\n ERROR");
    }
    System.out.println("\n - End test_array - ");

    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    ctx = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside your solution in Edit 3, it works perfect when you don't use connection-pooling like dbcp or c3p0. - You are working with dbcp.

A possible solution, when using c3p0 would be to use [proxool](http://proxool.sourceforge.net/). With this, there shouldn't be any problems, because proxool can handle `createArrayOf()`.

Another would be this:

```
    C3P0ProxyConnection connection = (C3P0ProxyConnection) _statement.getConnection();
    Method method = Connection.class.getMethod("createArrayOf", new Class[] { String.class, Object[].class });
    Array array = (Array) connection.rawConnectionOperation(
        method, C3P0ProxyConnection.RAW_CONNECTION, new Object[] {"integer", intArray});
    _statement.setArray(_i, array);
```

You need to get the underlying function from the jdbc-class. Therefor get it with `getMethod` and use it with reflection.