# How to map Integer array in Hibernate in hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I use prosgres sql and the table is like this.

CREATE TABLE invoice (
  id           INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  item_ids     INTEGER[] NOT NULL,
  seller   VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

Here I want to map the 'item_ids' array to the Integer array (Integer[]) in hbm.xml. This Integer array does not have any other references.Only an array Any sample code please.

Comment: Are you using any IDE?

Comment: Eclipse, Kepler is used. but I need to do it manually. :)

Comment: well you can go this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219498/array-with-usertype-in-hibernate-and-postgresql-mappingexception , or just use a List...

Answer (score 1):

You can't map `Integer` array in Hibernate. Use `List<Integer>` using `<list></list>` tags.

Comment: thanks for reply. then can you let me know  how about the column type should be ? What is the column type should be ?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332467/mapping-array-with-hibernate

Comment: You need mapping OneToMany or use @EllementCollection

Comment: I can't use annotations all hibernates are written as XML

Comment: or then can I use int[] (primitive type) ? if can any sample please ?

Comment: No, you can't use int[]

Comment: Most of examples on the internetr are about custome Objects savings as List.. Would you give sample how can map List of Integers to sql array please ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to modify your database structure to be as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, seller VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE invoice_items ( invoice_id INTEGER NOT NULL, item_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
```