# how to use postgresql array_agg function in JpaRepository spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-data-jpa

I have created new spring boot project with postgresql .I like to use posgressql array_agg(ex:get all department) using JPA Repository native query but its getting some error in blow posted. I have tried some alter solution but cant able to get expected data.

**Error** :

org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003;
nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003

**Expected** : Should get array or list of data

```
@Repository
public interface PostGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<PostGroup, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT array_agg(department) FROM boxinfo;", nativeQuery = true)
    public Object[] getDept();
}
```

[image: PostgreSQL Query]

Comment: what things have you tried?
As postgres returns datatype text[]  - JPA /Hibernate will not have datatype for that.
You need to do custom Data type mapping.

Comment: I just tried alternate queries only.if possible could give some example of custom data mapping @Lucia

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-array-java-list/
You can check this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21630370/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-2003

check this as well

Comment: @Lucia 
is possible to get directly in native query itself??without adding additional works?

Comment: without additional work it is not possible to do it. Even with native query it needs that custom type which will actually read the array into String Array of Java. And you need to register this custom type in the hibernate dialect.

Answer (score 2):

First solution is to use below dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

he has custom types already written and register that in the custom dialect like below

```
public class CustomPostgreDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect {
    public CustomPostgreDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(2003, StringArrayType.class.getName());
    }
}
```

And use this dialect as the hibernate dialect in application.yaml or application.properties of spring boot.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: <packageName>.CustomPostgreDialect
```

Second solution is to write the custom type yourself and register it in the dialect as shown above, if you don't want to use dependency.