# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Error

> org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Integer] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.entity.CombHoldingRule]

Entity Class is like below

```
    @Type(type = "int-array")
    @Column(
            name = "holdingrule_list",
            columnDefinition = "int[]"
    )
    private int[] holdingRuleList;//Checked
```

Repository :-

```
@Query(value="select combHoldingRuleId , " +
            "combHoldingRuleName, " +
            "jurisdictionId, " +
            "functionGroupId, " +
            "overallNettingType, " +
            "packageId ," +
            "holdingRuleList from CombHoldingRule where packageId=:packageId")
    //@Query(value=query,nativeQuery = true)
    List<CombHoldingRule> repoCHRFromPackageId(@Param("packageId") int packageId);
```

Comment: first thing do you have this int-array type custom type? and are you using any library for it

Comment: am not using any custom type, in the Entity class, import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.IntArrayType; being imported

Comment: have you registered this type into hibernate?

Comment: See this to how to register type into hibernate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768125/how-to-use-postgresql-array-agg-function-in-jparepository-spring-boot

Comment: `@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.entity.CombHoldingRule` is an extremely odd conversion target. Please post the full stack trace formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved

Solution that worked for me is below.

In the Entity Class

```
    @Type(type = "int-array")
    @Column(
            name = "holdingrule_list",
            columnDefinition = "integer[]"
    )
    private int[] holdingRuleList;
```

In the Repo

```
   @Query(value="from CombHoldingRule where packageId=:packageId")
    List<CombHoldingRule> repoCHRFromPackageId(@Param("packageId") int packageId);
```

Thank you @Jens Schauder for the guidance.