# Infer type information in UserType

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I've written a [`UserType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) for storing `List` fields as Postgres `ARRAY` columns. The type is [parameterised](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/ParameterizedType.html) so that I can tell it what kind of list I want to store (`String`, `Double`, etc). This means that I must specify it in my `.hbm.xml` file:

```
<property name="foo">
    <column name="foo" sql-type="text[]" />
    <type name="EmbeddedListType">
        <param name="elementType">string</param>
    </type>
</property>
```

I'd really like to not have to specify the `sql-type` and `elementType` in my config. So, I have two questions:

1. Is there some way to hook into Hibernate's configuration process to get the actual POJO field the type is being bound to?
2. How do I return something to set the `sql-type`? None of the methods in the `UserType` interface seem to be what I need. **Edit:** currently if I don't specify this, I get a `org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003`

I've tried implementing [`DynamicParameterizedType`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/DynamicParameterizedType.html), but the [properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/) object does not contain the `PARAMETER_TYPE` etc. fields. Maybe I need to configure it differently if I'm going to use a dynamic type?

Here is the full code for my [actual class](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/9cceb95efd1e79f3e58af3b0c820f1eb0817c1d8/src/storagemanager/src/main/java/org/vpac/ndg/storage/dao/EmbeddedListType.java) and [mapping file](https://github.com/vpac-innovations/rsa/blob/9cceb95efd1e79f3e58af3b0c820f1eb0817c1d8/src/storagemanager/src/main/resources/spring/hibernate/Statistics.hbm.xml#L91) (GPL3). Hitbernate `5.1.0.Final`, postgresql driver `9.4-1201-jdbc41`

### Edit: Defining My Own Types

I see that you can [extend a dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219498/array-with-usertype-in-hibernate-and-postgresql-mappingexception?rq=1) to define how JDBC type `2003` should be mapped to a column definition:

```
public class PostgreSQLDialectArray extends org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect {
    public PostgreSQLDialectArray() { 
        super(); 
        registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, "array"); 
    }
}
```

This should avoid the need for `sql-type` in the mapping, but Postgres rejects it, because the array itself needs to be typed, e.g. `"integer array"` and not just `"array"`. But Hibernate seems to map each `Types` int to a single value. Is it OK to define my own types? E.g. I could change my `UserType` to return:

```
public final static int LONGVARCHAR_ARRAY = 8000;
public final static int DOUBLE_ARRAY = 8001;

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    if (componentType == Double.class)
        return new int[] { DOUBLE_ARRAY };
    else if (componentType == String.class)
        return new int[] { LONGVARCHAR_ARRAY };
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

And then in my dialect:

```
registerHibernateType(EmbeddedListType.DOUBLE_ARRAY, "double precision[]");
registerHibernateType(EmbeddedListType.LONGVARCHAR_ARRAY, "text[]");
```

Or is that just asking for trouble? I mean, I've tested it and it seems to work.