# How to fix the Hibernate org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003

Tags: arrays, spring, postgresql, hibernate, custom-type

```
public void GetLevel(int id) 
    {
        Type doubleArrayType=new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver())
                .custom(DoubleArrayUserType.class);
        Query query =  sf.getCurrentSession().
                createSQLQuery("select waterLevel from FtpData").
                addScalar("waterLevel", doubleArrayType);


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Double[]> results=(List<Double[]>) query.list();
        System.out.println("In dao layer data:"+results);
        return;
    }
```

trying to access db which is having array of double for which i hav written user type class:::

```
package com.app.usertype;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;

public class DoubleArrayUserType implements UserType {
    protected static final int  SQLTYPE = java.sql.Types.ARRAY;

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor, final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
        Double[] javaArray = (Double[]) array.getArray();
        return ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(javaArray);
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object object, final int i, final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = statement.getConnection();

        double[] castObject = (double[]) object;
        Double[] doubles = ArrayUtils.toObject(castObject);
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("DOUBLE", doubles);

        statement.setArray(i, array);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o == null ? null : ((double[]) o).clone();
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) o;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == null ? y == null : x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o == null ? 0 : o.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<double[]> returnedClass() {
        return double[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { SQLTYPE };
    }
}
```

but it is giving error as:::

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
>     at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:76)   at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:99)    at
>   org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getTypeName(Dialect.java:297)   at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getSqlType(Column.java:227)  at
>   org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:373)   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1275)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:155)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:506)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5368)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

here is ma hibernate-persistent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- supply loc -->
    <context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath:/database.properties" />
    <!-- DS bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" 
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" 
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" 
        p:initialSize="1" p:maxActive="2"
        destroy-method="close">
    </bean>
    <!-- configure Hibernate 4 specific local session factory bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:packagesToScan="com.app.dto" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate

            </value>

        </property>
            </bean>
    <!-- configure tx mgr bean -->

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean> <!-- enable tx annotation suuport -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

properties

```
jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/glofdata
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=postgres
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Which DB do you use and which Dialect is configured?

Comment: Ma DB contains an array of Double precision values and a i am trying to retrieve it

Comment: I have updated my post mentioning the dialect

Comment: postgres 9.3.14

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate does not supports `database arrays` (e.g. `java.sql.Array`)

`array` and `primitive-array` types provided by Hibernate are for mapping Java arrays into backing table - they're basically a variation of one-to-many / collection-of-elements mappings.

Here, is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219498/array-with-usertype-in-hibernate-and-postgresql-mappingexception) for Postgresql in which @Alex have sorted out this problem by himself using the `UserType for integer arrays`. Also, this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate)  is related to mapping a postgres array with hibernate.
Hope this helps.

Comment: canu tell me the solution

Comment: how to retrieve array from db

Answer (score 4):

Although Hibernate does not support ARRAY types natively, you can use the [`Hibernate Types`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) project for that.

Now, even if you are using the [`StringArrayType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) or [`IntArrayType`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) supplied by Hibernate Types, as long as you are using JPQL, the array types will be resolved properly.

It is only when you are using native SQL that the `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type` issue can occur. To solve it, you have to option:

1. You can register the missing JDBC type at the Dialect level:

   ```
   public class PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {
       public PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect() {
           super();
           this.registerColumnType(Types.ARRAY, "array");
       }
   }
   ```

   And register the [`PostgreSQL95ArrayDialect`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type/) via the `hibernate.dialect` configuration property.
2. You can register the type at the query level via the `addScalar` method:

   ```
   String[] array = (String[]) entityManager.createNativeQuery("""
       SELECT properties
       FROM book
       WHERE isbn = :isbn
       """)
   .setParameter("isbn", "978-9730228236")
   .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
   .addScalar("properties", StringArrayType.INSTANCE)
   .getSingleResult();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add the @OneToMany anotation. Just a small headsup for future readers :)
For example:

```
public class Doctor extends BaseEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2135533192903332964L;
    
    @OneToMany
    protected final List<Patient> patients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```