# Hibernate UserType error

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I am trying to map BigDecimal array into postgresql via hibernate using my UserType class but it throws an error: "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003".
I am using hibernate 5 and postgresql 9.4-1206-jdbc42.
My model contains:

```
@Column(name = "prices")
@Type(type = "com.hms.domain.customTypes.BigDecimalArrayType")
private BigDecimal[] prices;
```

Here is my UserData class:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.*;


public class BigDecimalArrayType implements UserType {
    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = {Types.ARRAY};

    public final int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    public Class returnedClass() {
        return BigDecimal[].class;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == y; 
    }

    public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
        return x.hashCode();
    }

    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
        BigDecimal[] javaArray = (BigDecimal[]) array.getArray();
        if (javaArray == null) { return new BigDecimal(0);}
        return javaArray;
    }

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = st.getConnection();
        BigDecimal[] bigDecimals = (BigDecimal[]) value;
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("NUMERIC", bigDecimals);
        //Array array = session.connection().createArrayOf("NUMERIC", bigDecimals);
        if (null != array){
            st.setArray(index, array);
        } else {
            st.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
        }
    }

    public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return value == null ? null : ((BigDecimal[]) value).clone();
    }

    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) this.deepCopy(value);
    }

    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(cached);
    }

    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(original);
    }
}
```

I have read many posts and it seems that my code should be fine. But there are something wrong.
P.S: Sorry for my english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mapping a postgres array with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate) or [array with usertype in hibernate and postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219498/array-with-usertype-in-hibernate-and-postgresql-mappingexception)

Comment: I am using hibernate 5 and postgres 9.4-1206-jdbc42. So there are no duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found a solution.
The problem was that the PostgreSQL9Dialect does not know about array type. So, i added my own extension to it by creating this class:

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect;    
import java.sql.Types;

public class ArrayPostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {
    public ArrayPostgreSQLDialect() {
        super();
        /*
         *You can change the "numeric[]" type to any other you want.
        */
        this.registerColumnType(Types.ARRAY, "numeric[]");
    }
}
```

Then i am changed settings in hibernate properties file - instead of

`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect`

i have typed the path to my own class

```
<prop key="hibernate.dialect">//path//.ArrayPostgreSQLDialect</prop>
```

And after that, hibernate created column with type "numeric[]" in my database.
That is all.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.*;

public class BigDecimalArrayUserType implements UserType {

    protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable arg0, Object arg1) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(arg0);
    }

@Override
public Object deepCopy(Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return convert((Object[]) arg0);
}

@Override
public Serializable disassemble(Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return (BigDecimal[]) this.deepCopy(arg0);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object arg0, Object arg1) throws HibernateException {
    if (arg0 == null) {
        return arg1 == null;
    }
    return arg0.equals(arg1);
}

@Override
public int hashCode(Object arg0) throws HibernateException {
    return arg0.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    /*
     * System.out.println(names[0]); System.out.println(resultSet.getArray(names[0]));
     */
    if (null == names[0]) {
        return null;
    }
    if (null == resultSet) {
        return null;
    }
    if (resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null) {
        if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Long[0];
    } else {
        Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
        Object[] oldArr = (Object[]) array.getArray();
        return convert(oldArr);
    }
}

private BigDecimal[] convert(Object[] oldArr){
    if(oldArr==null){
        return null;
    }
    BigDecimal[] javaArray = new BigDecimal[oldArr.length];
    for(int i =0 ; i< oldArr.length; i++){
        javaArray[i]= new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(oldArr[i]));
    }
    return javaArray;
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
    if (value == null) {
        statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
    } else {
        BigDecimal[] castObject = convert((Object[])value);

        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("numeric", castObject);
        statement.setArray(index, array);
    }
}

@Override
public Object replace(Object arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) throws HibernateException {
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public Class<BigDecimal[]> returnedClass() {
    return BigDecimal[].class;
}

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
}
```

}

Comment: You should add some explanation.